# laggy css transition in safari depending on items count

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm facing laggy `width` css transition (1200px to 100%) on a `position:sticky` div living beside a list of div items.

Chrome and Firefox runs smoothly.

The more items div on the page, the more the transition is laggy on Safari.

I've tried

```
transform: translateZ(0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
perspective: 1000;
```

with no success.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using the web-prefix for safari?

Comment: yes it's -webkit- prefixed